# Parse links and replace with http://

Tags: php, regex

I have the following link list:

```
$lines = array(
  "www.google.com", 
  "https://stackoverflow.com", 
  "facebook.com", 
  "https://www.gmail.com",
  "http://www.gmail.com",  
  "http://gmail.com",
  "http://www.facebook.com/top", 
  "https://facebook.com/top", 
);

foreach ($lines as $value) {
    echo preg_replace("^(http|https)://www.*", "http://", $value);
}
```

I am trying to replace every link with `http://` in the beginning. For example, my link list would become:

```
  "www.google.com" => http://google.com 
  "https://stackoverflow.com" => http://stackoverflow.com 
  "facebook.com" => http://facebook.com
  "https://www.gmail.com" => http://gmail.com
  "http://www.gmail.com" => http://gmail.com  
  "http://gmail.com" => http://gmail.com
  "http://www.facebook.com/top" => http://facebook.com  
  "https://facebook.com/top" => http://facebook.com
```

I am using the following the following regular expression: `^(http|https)://www.*`

However, my regular expression is not working.

Any suggestions what I should change on my regex that its working?

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: _However, my regular expression is not working._ - a little bit more specific?

Comment: Why replacing everything with http:// and not with //?

Comment: Firstly: why replace with `http://` and make all links insecure? Secondly, why remove `www.` from the URL? _Some_ domains might not have the base domain forward to their website.

Comment: You won't hit `"www.google.com" => https://google.com` with that regex

Comment: The closest I came up with is [`preg_replace("~^(https?://)?~", "http://", $lines)`](https://ideone.com/Gt1JOZ). Note there is no need in `foreach ($lines as $value)` as `preg_replace` also accepts arrays as input. If `"www.google.com" => https://google.com` is as typo in the expected results, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `www.google.com` should turn into `http://google.com` you may use

```
preg_replace("~^(https?://)?~i", "http://", $lines)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Gt1JOZ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxNWsV/3).

Note:

- `preg_replace` accepts an array as input, no need to `foreach`
- PHP regexps should be used inside regex delimiters (here, I suggest `~` since the pattern contains `/`)

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `http` - a `http` substring
  - `s?` - 1 or 0 `s`
  - `://` - a `://` substring

So, the regex will match `http://`, `https://` or just an empty string at the start of a string and replace with `http://`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the regular-expression to `preg_replace("/^(http|https):\/\//ismx", "http://", $value);`, which replaces every `https://` to `http://`. However, you also want `google.com` and `facebook.com` to be `http://`, but the regular-expression does not work here. For this part, use `strpos` to find out a string has an `http://` beginning or not.

**The code would be similar to this**

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {
    $value = preg_replace("/^(http|https):\/\//i", "http://", $value);
    $pos = strpos($value,'http://');
    $pos2 = strpos($value,'www.');
    if($pos === false){
        $value = "http://".$value;
    }
    if($pos2 === true){
        $value = str_replace("www.","",$value);
    }
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

There, the regex changes every `http://` to `https://` and checks if a domain has a `www.` inside itself or if a domain has the `http://` beginning. Then it changes every string without `http://` to `http://` and removes the `www.` from the domain.

**Now, the expected output is this**

```
http://www.google.com
http://stackoverflow.com
http://facebook.com
http://www.gmail.com
http://www.gmail.com
http://gmail.com
http://www.facebook.com/top
http://facebook.com/top
```

For further reading, you can check the `strpos` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

The regex is written by @web-nomad!

Comment: Just note that since the input is an array of single-line strings, you do not need to use `m` modifier (`^` does not have to match all line start positions), and the `x` is not necessary since you are not using comments nor formatting whitespace. `s` is redundant as there is no `.` in the pattern.